# Why is tsc called twice in this npm start script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

The `package.json` example [at this link](https://github.com/opdahlmann/Angular2Start-RC6/blob/master/package.json) includes the following `start` commands:

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
```

**What *explicitly* does the above command do?**

I think that the `"concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "` means to start both `tsc` and `lite-server` simultaneously, and to also place a `watch` on the `tsc` so that changes are reloaded into `lite-server` immediately.  Is this correct?  And also, why call `tsc` twice?  What is an explicit explanation of the entire line of code including all of its constituent parts put together?

Comment: Can I see your whole `scripts` object in `package.json`?

Comment: @AndrewLi Please refresh this page.  It should be in the hyperlink in the OP, which I added a minute after the original post.  Are you able to see it in the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break it down the command into parts (with quotes removed):

1. `tsc`
2. `concurrently`
3. `npm run tsc:w`
4. `npm run lite`

The first part calls the TypeScript compiler CLI and compiles your TypeScript files.

Next, there is an `&&` which means "`cmd1` then/and `cmd2`". The next section:

```
concurrently npm run tsc:w npm run lite
```

Uses the [`concurrently` package CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run the given commands, which are `npm run tsc:w` and `npm run lite`. The part:

```
npm run tsc:w
```

This runs the script in your `package.json`:

```
"tsc:w": "tsc -w"
```

Then `npm run lite` runs the corresponding script in `package.json`:

```
"lite": "lite-server"
```

So you're technically calling `tsc` twice but `tsc:w` starts watching your TypeScript files. **Using `-w` does not do an initial build, so the first `tsc` is needed to build your files initially**, then `-w` watches your files and rebuilds subsequent changed files. The `concurrent` script then runs the watch script and the server.